# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat7

Im trying to integrate spring with JSF and I added the following in web.xml,

```
<listener>  
<listener-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>  
</listener>  

<listener> 
<listener-class>
 org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
</listener-class>    
</listener>
```

I have also added spring-web and common logging in my tomcat classpath in eclipse

There are no build errors , but while running on tomcat 7 im getting the following error,

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

and

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

These are my settings,

- There is a servlet-api jar in tomcat lib
- In my Pom.xml I have given

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency> 

   and            
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax</groupId>
          <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
          <version>6.0</version>
      </dependency>
  ```

I have tried commenting out the entry in pom.xml also this also but no luck.
Any help will be appreciated.

This is my pom.xml,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>TimeTracker</groupId>
<artifactId>TimeTracker</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
<id>Java.Net</id>
<url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- J2ee -->

          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
             <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency> 

    <!-- Spring framework -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

<!-- JSR-330 -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and the other thing I have noticed is the jar files which gets copied during deployment. Im running the project in tomcat 7 in eclipse. This is the entries in deployment assembly
/src                             WEB-INF/classes
/WebContent                        /
JSF 2.1 (Apache MyFaces 2.1.5)   WEB-INF/lib

is it ok?  or do I have to add maven dependencies also?.but on adding maven dependencies a error mark appears on the project and on maven -> project update. The cross error and the maven dependency entry also disappears on update. Wel, I am trying to integrate JSF with spring

Thanks,
Pegasus

Comment: yes, I changed the scope to 'provided' for both jars and tried to run after cleaning the tomcat work directory. Im getting the same error.

Comment: can you please paste your complete pom here .

Comment: yes, I have posted my pom file above

Answer (score 2):

As a standard practice you should not bundle any servlet related jars with your war file , let your app server (in your case it is tomcat) provide the required classes at runtime.

Change the scope to provided ,bundle your war file again and try to deploy.

```
    <scope>provided</scope>
```

Comment: Yes, I did give the scope 'provided' but still i have the issue

Answer (score 1):

The servlet-api is a classic example of a dependency which should have the `provided` scope, see [Introduction to dependency mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).